# Loop posts in a table ordered by a custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, date, events, table

I'm trying to generate a table for a custom post type events, in which I have a few custom fields, one of these is the date. I want to display the posts in the table and order them by the Date value. This is my code:

**Date format**: 07/07/2015 (DAY/MONTH/YEAR)

Right now, the loop isn't working and I don't know how to order by the date.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Artista</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Información</th>
          </tr>
        <?php $i = 0;?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if($i == 0){ echo "<tr>"; }?>
                <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                <td><?php the_field('fecha_del_evento'); ?></td>
                <td><?php the_field('lugar_del_evento'); ?></td>
                <td><?php the_content(); ?></td>
            <?php $i++;?>
            <?php if($i == 4){ echo "</tr>"; $i=0;}?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php if($i < 4) echo '</tr>'; ?>
        </table>

        <?php else:  ?>
          <div class="page-header"><h1>Uh Oh!</h1></div>
          <p>Sorry, for some reason the contents of this page isn't displaying.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>


  </div><!-- END OF ROW -->
</div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: In what format is your date in your custom field

Comment: @PieterGoosen It is 07/07/2015 (DAY/MONTH/YEAR)

Comment: You are not going to sort by date with that format unfortunately. Your dates in custom fields must be stored as unix timestamp or `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ok, I can change how the date is stored. [link] (http://i.imgur.com/yj5UMjG.png)

Comment: Note, you need to have the correct format stored in db, otherwise it will not work

Comment: I have posted an answer, you decided to ignore it, I have deleted it and undeleted it now again. Strange to see an update now on your question. You might get help if you take your time and **respond back** to comments and answers given. Without that, no one knows where you are having issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which displays the posts ordered by the date value, and also removes the past ones.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  

     <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Artista</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Ciudad</th>
        <th>Información</th>
      </tr>

      <?php
      $today = current_time('Ymd');

      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'evento',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today,
            )
          ),
        'meta_key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );

      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
      ?>
      <?php $i = 0;?>
      <?php if($i == 0){ echo "<tr>"; }?>
      <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
      <?php $i++;?>
      <td><?php the_field('fecha_del_evento'); ?></td>
      <?php $i++;?>
      <td><?php the_field('lugar_del_evento'); ?></td>
      <?php $i++;?>
      <td><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></td>
      <?php $i++;?>
      <?php if($i == 4){ echo "</tr>"; $i=0;}?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php if($i < 4) echo '</tr>'; ?>
  </table>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- END OF ROW -->
</div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

Notice that this code (inside the proper query, of course) would be enough to order the posts by date:

```
'meta_key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            );
```

Comment: Note, running custom queries in place of the main query is expensive and unnecessary.

Comment: Hello @PieterGoosen thanks for your answer, but I'm not a coder and don't know how to implement a normal query to solve this case. I used this because is what I found. In addition, you mention "expensive" regarding performance, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, on which template is this. From your question I took that this is not a page template. If it is a page template, yes, then my approach will not work, then you will have to use yours, there are no other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup as to what you were going for. This block of code goes in the template file:

```
    <?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key'  => 'date',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
));


// loop
if( $posts ) {

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {

        setup_postdata( $post );

        // do something

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

}

?>                                  



<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="schedule-header">
                <th scope="col" class="header-cell schedule-cell">Date</th>
                <th scope="col" class="header-cell schedule-cell">Time</th>
                <th scope="col" class="header-cell schedule-cell">Venue</th>
                <th scope="col" class="header-cell schedule-cell">Address</th>
                <th scope="col" class="header-cell schedule-cell">Tix</th>                              
            </tr>
        </tbody>    


<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-front-page'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <h5>Sorry! Either I have been too lazy to put in my show dates or no one is booking me because they're mad at me. Are you mad at me?</h5>

<?php endif; ?>

    </table
```

This block of code goes in the functions.php:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {

    return $query;

}


// only modify queries for 'event' post type
if( isset($query->query_vars['post']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post' ) {

    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
    $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');   
    $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 

}


// return
return $query;

}
```